# Dependency Error Phanom - spark cassandra connector

Tags: cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, phantom-dsl

I'm getting the following error while executing:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.datastax.driver.core.DefaultResultSetFuture does not implement the requested interface com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1184)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.CassandraOperations$class.scalaQueryStringToPromise(CassandraOperations.scala:80)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.Query.scalaQueryStringToPromise(Query.scala:52)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.CassandraOperations$class.scalaQueryStringExecuteToFuture(CassandraOperations.scala:31)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.Query.scalaQueryStringExecuteToFuture(Query.scala:52)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.ExecutableStatement$class.future(ExecutableQuery.scala:81)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.Query.future(Query.scala:52)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.ExecutableQuery$class.fetch(ExecutableQuery.scala:247)
    at com.outworkers.phantom.builder.query.SelectQuery.fetch(SelectQuery.scala:33)
```

I think it is dependency problem between the guava versions of spark cassandra connector and phantom cassandra connector but I cant find the mistake.

This is my dependency tree:

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myvalue ---
[INFO] es.example.myvalue:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- es.example:core:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ses:jar:1.11.122:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.122:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.6.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.122:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.11.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-mapred:jar:hadoop2:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:jar:tests:1.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.twitter:chill_2.11:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.esotericsoftware:kryo-shaded:jar:3.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- com.esotericsoftware:minlog:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.twitter:chill-java:jar:0.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-asm5-shaded:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-app:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-client:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |  \- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |     +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  |     \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-server-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-launcher_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-common_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.fusesource.leveldbjni:leveldbjni-all:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-network-shuffle_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-unsafe_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.curator:curator-framework:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.curator:curator-client:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ning:compress-lzf:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.jpountz.lz4:lz4:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.roaringbitmap:RoaringBitmap:jar:0.5.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:jar:2.4.0-b34:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.18.1-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty-all:jar:4.0.42.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.8.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.clearspring.analytics:stream:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-jvm:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-json:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-graphite:jar:3.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.11:jar:2.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-paranamer:jar:2.6.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- oro:oro:jar:2.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.razorvine:pyrolite:jar:4.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.sf.py4j:py4j:jar:0.10.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-tags_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-crypto:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.spark-project.spark:unused:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.univocity:univocity-parsers:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-sketch_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.spark:spark-catalyst_2.11:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.antlr:antlr4-runtime:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-column:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-encoding:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-hadoop:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.apache.parquet:parquet-format:jar:2.3.0-incubating:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.parquet:parquet-jackson:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:jar:2.0.0-M3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.twitter:jsr166e:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.joda:joda-convert:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.databricks:spark-xml_2.11:jar:0.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.11.8:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.11.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11:jar:5.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:jar:2.1.0:optional
[INFO] |  +- com.github.gphat:wabisabi_2.11:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.databinder.dispatch:dispatch-core_2.11:jar:0.11.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.ning:async-http-client:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.clapper:grizzled-slf4j_2.11:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.netaporter:scala-uri_2.11:jar:0.4.3:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.parboiled:parboiled_2.11:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.typesafe.akka:akka-actor_2.11:jar:2.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.typesafe:config:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.11:jar:0.7.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.websudos:phantom-dsl_2.11:jar:1.29.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.websudos:phantom-connectors_2.11:jar:1.29.6:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.typelevel:macro-compat_2.11:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.outworkers:diesel-reflection_2.11:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.outworkers:diesel-engine_2.11:jar:0.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.chuusai:shapeless_2.11:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.0.37.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:16.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jnr-ffi:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:1.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- com.github.jnr:jffi:jar:native:1.2.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-analysis:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm-util:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-x86asm:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- com.github.jnr:jnr-posix:jar:3.0.27:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.github.jnr:jnr-constants:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-extras:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.outworkers:phantom-streams_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.outworkers:phantom-dsl_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.outworkers:phantom-connectors_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.typesafe.play:play-streams_2.11:jar:2.5.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.typesafe.akka:akka-stream_2.11:jar:2.4.10:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- com.typesafe:ssl-config-akka_2.11:jar:0.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     |        \- com.typesafe:ssl-config-core_2.11:jar:0.2.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.typesafe.play:play-iteratees_2.11:jar:2.5.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.scala-stm:scala-stm_2.11:jar:0.7:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- es.example:categorization:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.json:json:jar:20160810:compile
[INFO] +- org.scalaj:scalaj-http_2.11:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] \- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.11:jar:3.3.0.RC2:compile
[INFO]    \- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.11:jar:3.3.0.RC2:compile
[INFO]       +- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.11:jar:3.3.0.RC2:compile
[INFO]       +- org.json4s:json4s-scalap_2.11:jar:3.3.0.RC2:compile
[INFO]       \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.7:compile
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you upgrade to phantom 2.7.6? This isn't really related to phantom per se as much as you seem to have a Guava version problem, but I'm pretty sure we fixed that in newer releases.

Comment: I update com.outworkers:phantom-streams_2.11:jar:2.5.0:compile to the newest version but It fails again. I saw that guava versions problems may occurs because of the phantom dsl version (1.29.6) but there is no new version since the last year..

Comment: I'm not sure where you are checking for new versions. https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/releases